# Google Sheets - How to copy submitted Form Responses to a Sheet & Move a row to another Sheet when selected "complete" from drop down menu

Tags: forms, validation, google-sheets, copy, move

I know there have been similar things asked, but haven't been able to quite get what I need, although I know I'm close. I have a decent understanding of HTML/CSS but never worked with VBS or Google Apps Script before and I'm a bit lost.

Basically I have a project tracker, video production to be specific. I have set up a Google Form so it's easy for the producer to start a project off, I've linked that to a Google Sheets, which works fine.

Now I want to copy any new entries from "FORM RESPONSES 1" to the "Active Projects" sheet, it could be 1 entry or 10 before I check the sheet, so it needs to be able to copy multiple rows. I did try =IMPORTAGE and =ARRAYFORMULA, but that doesn't give people the ability to edit say the "Due Date" or "Additional Info" for example.

So it has to be a copy script I would assume, this is what I've tried.

```
function onFormSubmit(e){
var responses = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Form Responses 1");
var projects = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Active Projects");
var lastrow = responses.getLastRow();
var col = responses.getLastColumn();
var row = responses.getRange(lastrow, 1, 1, col).getValues();

projects.appendRow(row[0]);
copyValuesOnly(copyFromRange, copyToRangeStart);
}
```

I haven't managed to get that working in any shape yet.

There is a complication though that info will be moved from the sheet "Active Projects" to another sheet "Completed Projects", so I don't want it to end up copying (re)moved rows, which leads me on to the second bit of code I need help with.

I want to have a "status" drop down menu ('list of items' via 'data validation', with say "active, needs review, and completed" (or a check box for completed if it's gonna be too difficult), so when "completed" is selected that entire row is moved (copied and deleted essentially) to the "Completed Projects" sheet.

```
function onEdit(e) {

var s = e.source.getActiveSheet();
if (s.getName() !== "Active Projects" || e.range.columnStart !== 1 || e.value !== "Completed") return;
e.source.getSheetByName("Completed Projects")
 .appendRow(s.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 1, 1, s.getLastColumn())
  .getValues()
  .reduce(function (a, b) {
    return a.concat(b)
   }))
  e.range.offset(0, 1)
s.deleteRow(e.range.rowStart);
}
```

This almost works, however, because when the "deleteRow" executes (row 5 for example), the row below (row 6) moves up in its place (to row 5), and because the drop menu values (in row 6) don't follow the row up (to row 5), the drop down menu in row 5 remains selected at "Completed", so the script just loops and will move every row with data in it there is!

Any explicit help would be greatly appreciated, I did start off with an Excel file that did mostly what I wanted but then discovered that some people involved don't have Microsoft Office, so I need an alternative and given Google Sheets is very multi user friendly, its a good option.

Thanks in advance for reading and offering any help.

Comment: Can you provide a sample spreadsheet? I think that it will help users image your situation. Of course, please remove your private information from the sample sheet.

Comment: Sure here's a copy of what I have done so far.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12ad8mKTD2nxFtxI8FLgLBkbk61tGtFYm_DBxHDFD9hI/edit?usp=sharing